# Is it possible to check the return of a function, if true assigning the value to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For something simple like:

```
def my_func(x):
    if x == 4:
        return 25
    return False

result = my_func(4)

if result:
    print(result)
```

is it possible to check the result and assign the return value in one line?
Something like:

```
if my_func(4) => x:
    print(x)
```

Comment: `return 25 if x == 4 else False`

Comment: Note that duplicate closure does not mean you were required to know this already, nor that the question should contain the answer now. A question closed as duplicate serves as a signpost to its target so that multiple ways of asking for the same thing lead to the same place where the information is collected.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a [ternary expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) can be used, such as:

```
return 25 if x == 4 else False
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to assign the value in one line, not to make the function one line